# Compare the value of the first click with the value of the second click in LUA (Corona SDK)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a scene with two objects created and I would like to store the object's value in a variable to compare whether the two are the same or different.
How can I do? Help me please.

```
local function click( event )
    print( "Tap event on: " .. event.target.id )
    if (click1 == click2) then
        print("is true")
    else
        print("is false")
    end
    return true
end

object1 = display.newImage("img/card1.png")
object1.x = 30
object1.y = 30
object1.name = "obj1"   
object1.id = "obj1"
object1:addEventListener("tap",click)
group:insert(object1)

object2 = display.newImage("img/card2.png")
object2.x = 30
object2.y = 30
object2.name = "obj2"   
object2.id = "obj2"
object2:addEventListener("tap",click)
group:insert(object2)
```

Comment: Don't know anything about Corona but if you create a global var lastClick and set `lastClick = event.target.id` on each click AFTER evaluating if `lastClick == event.target.id` you can compare the last click to the new click. Should work in theory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if two tables(objects) have the same value in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325332/how-to-check-if-two-tablesobjects-have-the-same-value-in-lua)

Answer (score 0):

In your title you say you want to compare "clicks" so I was assuming that you want to compare the x and y coordinates of each click. But in your actual description it sounds like you want to compare those two lua tables `object1` and `object2` with each other.

You can't use `==` here, because it doesn't compare the contents of each table, but wether or not they point to the same memory location.

To compare them, you'll have to write your own code, which performs a "deep" comparison and checks the necessary values in both tables for equality.

For example, this would check if both objects are at the same location:

```lua
object1 = {}
object1.x = 30
object1.y = 30

object2 = {}
object2.x = 30
object2.y = 30

if object1.x == object2.x and object1.y == object2.y then
  print("foo")
end
```