# Breakup of months between two Dates

Tags: lua

i need a loop where `x` and `y` are two input variable,
now I want to get a resulting array in which all period between these two dates are breakup in months.
For example,  `x = 1.1.2019` and `y = 31.3.2019`,
result would be array like 
`1.1.2019, 31.1.2019, 1.2.2019, 28.2.2019, 1.3.2019, 31.3.2019`using LUA programming language.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = os.time{year=2019, month=1, day=1}
y = os.time{year=2019, month=3, day=31}

df = {}
i = 2
sec_day = 24*60*60
df[1] = x
while x <= y do
     x = x +sec_day
     df[i] = x
     i = i+1
end

--loop to get unique months
hash={}
d_months = {}
for _,v in ipairs(df) do
    if (not hash[os.date('%m',v)]) then
        d_months[#d_months+1] = os.date('%m', v)
        hash[os.date('%m',v)] = true
    end
end

--now everything is set up and we can iterate over the months to get the start and end days of the month
min_d = {}
max_d = {}
for idx,month in ipairs(d_months) do
    min = nil
    max = nil
    for _,v in ipairs(df) do
         if os.date('%m', v) == month then
             min = min or v
             max = max or v
             min = min < v and min or v
             max = max > v and max or v
         end
     end
 min_d[idx] = os.date('%d.%m.%Y', min)
 max_d[idx] = os.date('%d.%m.%Y', max)
 print(os.date('%d.%m.%Y', min) .. " " .. os.date('%d.%m.%Y', max))
 end
```

A short explanation beyond the commentaries. First we get a table of each date between (and including) start and end date.
In the next loop we are looking for an array of unique months (see [Lua : remove duplicate elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066835/lua-remove-duplicate-elements)).
And finally we iterate over the array of all dates and find minimum and maximum for each month.

Output

```
01.01.2019 31.01.2019
01.02.2019 28.02.2019
01.03.2019 31.03.2019
```

If you want to have it for years to, just do 2 extra loops. Once you need to find the unique years and then you need to compare not only for months but also for years in the last part.

Edit: changed format of output format.

Comment: I got this output
01/01/19 01/31/19
02/01/19 02/28/19
03/01/19 03/31/19
04/01/19 04/01/19

Comment: That is due to the standard formatting of lua. The timestamps are correct. If you want to have the output you desire, just write one more loop to put everything in correct order

Comment: instead of putting format as `%x` use `%d.%m.%Y` to get the desired format